# handling hanging shell command in ruby

Tags: ruby, bash

I have a cronjob that runs a ruby scrip that collects data from a bash utility (ipmitool). Sometimes this utility hangs, causing the whole script to hang, causing the cron jobs to stack up...

the line of code that does this is:

```
'macaddress' => `timeout 5 ipmitool lan print | grep 'MAC Address'`.split(':',2)[1].strip
```

in the cron job this still causes the script to hang but when I manually test the following in a ruby script & run form terminal:

```
ans = `timeout 1 sleep 20 | grep 'hello'`
```

the shell command terminates properly

how can I prevent the cron script from hanging?

edit: Here's strace of the hanging (hang is at select) :

```
open("/root/.freeipmi/sdr-cache/sdr-cache-xxxx.localhost", O_RDONLY) = 4
mmap(NULL, 2917, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 4, 0) = 0x7f0ea2dfd000
ioctl(3, IPMICTL_SEND_COMMAND, 0x7fff74802020) = 0
select(4, [3], NULL, NULL, {60, 0}
```

Comment: What is the state of the processes involved when this job hangs? Is the hang repeatable or random?

Comment: It's "random" in the sense that it could be a perfect storm of processes that are causing the ipmi kernel modules to be unresponsive, but it could also be dodgy hardware - investigation of that is ongoing, though I need to make sure this script can handle it in the meantime.

Comment: Part of my question was that depending on what exactly is happening when it hangs you literally may not be able to kill it. IO sleep, as far as I know, is uninterruptible. Which means the best you can do is find some way to run it (background/etc. writing to a file/socket/etc.) such that it hanging doesn't hang your process and you can check for output after some period of time and give up if it hasn't given it to you by then.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the hang manually - it's intermittently occurring on a live server at the moment.

Comment: What does recovery from the problem look like at the moment? Do the hanging processes go away without a reboot?

Comment: the one time I've managed to catch it, killing all the stacked processes using the kernel modules and unloading/reloading the ipmi kernel modules is what did the trick so no in-script recovery happened - though http://sourceforge.net/p/ipmitool/bugs/333/ would seem to suggest it will happily collect input if it finally comes?

Comment: You could kill the shell process if no output appears after a given timeout. You would need to launch the shell using proc using `popen()` and then select the procs output with a timeout. If the timeout is reached then kill the process.